# Php Json Data format

Tags: php, rest

There is a curl POST request example sent via REST JSON.

```
{"email": "sam@email.com", "items": [{ "name": "api Name", "quantity": 10, "unit_price": 2}, { "name": "api 2", "quantity": "4", "unit_price": 3 }] 

}
```

How can I format this in PHP.

I have tried the following:

```
$data = array(
        'email' => 'john@dow.com', 
        );
$data['items'] = array(
        'name' => 'fruits', 'quantity' => 4,
         'unit_price' => 7,
        );
```

The service just accepts `email`, and ignores `items`.

Comment: The example contains two objects inside the `items` array, your structure contains three scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

the `items` array is an array of objects. You are showing an map of strings

Answer (score 0):

An easy trick is to use the PHP function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get a PHP data structure that, when passed to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) produces the string you need:

```
var_export(json_decode(
    '{"email": "sam@email.com", "items": [{ "name": "api Name", "quantity": 10, "unit_price": 2}, { "name": "api 2", "quantity": "4", "unit_price": 3 }]}',
    TRUE
));
```

produces:

```
array(
    'email' => 'sam@email.com',
    'items' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'api Name',
            'quantity' => 10,
            'unit_price' => 2,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'api 2',
            'quantity' => '4',
            'unit_price' => 3,
        ),
    ),
)
```

Pass `TRUE` as the second argument to get arrays back; without it, `json_decode()` generates objects instead of associative arrays.

Use function [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to get the PHP code that generates the data structure you pass it as argument.

*Use the code above in a separate script, to get a hint about the data structure you need to create in order to get the desired string when you encode it as JSON. Don't put it into the product you develop.*